# Suitescript 2.0 Utilize different forms for different types of projects

Tags: netsuite

My company runs several different types of projects and would like to view the project record differently depending on the type of project being run in the selected project record.

I have the field that selects the form to use, which is titled "custom form" (this is a select field) and a field that our staff enter the type of project "custentityjt_fie_pro_projecttype" (also a select field).

I have created the following before load user event script to try to achieve this:

```
/**
* @NApiVersion 2.x
* @NScriptType UserEventScript
* @NModuleScope SameAccount
*/
define(["N/record"], function(r)  {
function beforeLoad(context)  {
    var currentRecord = context.newRecord;
    var projectType = currentRecord.getValue({
        fieldId: "custentityjt_fie_pro_projecttype",
    });

    currentRecord.setValue({
        fieldID: 'customform',
        value: projectType
        })

}

return {
    beforeLoad: beforeLoad,
}

})
```

When loading the project record in edit mode, the custom form selection does not change, and when loading the project record in view mode, I get the following:

```
{"type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"UNEXPECTED_ERROR","message":null,"stack":["anonymous(N/recordService)","beforeLoad(/SuiteScripts/setForm.js:13)"],"cause":{"type":"internal error","code":"UNEXPECTED_ERROR","details":null,"userEvent":"beforeload","stackTrace":["anonymous(N/recordService)","beforeLoad(/SuiteScripts/setForm.js:13)"],"notifyOff":false},"id":"","notifyOff":false}
```

I'm very new to Netsuite and programming in general so please be gentle :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a Client Script in order to change the Custom Form. Best bet would be to do it in two places, a pageInit() and a fieldChanged(). Another potential issue would be trying to set the Custom form value to a value that was retrieved in the getValue of your field custentityjt_fie_pro_projecttype. The value returned from the currentRecord.getValue() from your example will be the internal id of the custom list value for the Project Type that is set there (go back to your custom list and you will see the internal id values listed). That is an issue because when setting the value of Custom Form field you will need to reference the Internal Id of the Custom Form you wish to use. It would be remarkable if the Internal ID of the Project Type referenced ever matched the Custom Form Internal Id. My recommendation would be to create a hash table in your code to store the references (assuming your list of Project Types didn't frequently change). Give this a try (just make sure you update the values in the lookup variable as those are made up.

```
/**
*@NApiVersion 2.x
*@NScriptType ClientScript
*/
define([
   'N/record'
],
  function (
    nsRecord
) {
    //
    // lookup table where the object property represents the internal IDs of the 
    // custom list values, and the value of each property represents the 
    // internal id's of the Custom Forms you wish to associate with each list value.
    //
    var lookup = {
        1: 122,
        2: 123,
        3: 125,
        4: 136
    };

    function fieldChanged(context) {
        var field = context.fieldId;
        var rec = context.currentRecord;
        var projId;

        if (field === 'custentityjt_fie_pro_projecttype' && rec.getValue('custentityjt_fie_pro_projecttype')) {
            projId = rec.getValue('custentityjt_fie_pro_projecttype');

            if (lookup[projId]) {
                rec.setValue({
                    fieldId: 'customform',
                    value: lookup[projId],
                    ignoreFieldChange: true,
                    fireSlavingSync: true
                });
            }
        }
    }

    function pageInit(context) {
        var rec = context.currentRecord;
        var mode = context.mode;
        var projId;
        var formId;

        if (mode !== 'create') {
            formId = rec.getValue('customform');
            projId = rec.getValue('custentityjt_fie_pro_projecttype');

            if (lookup[projId] && lookup[projId] !== formId) {
                rec.setValue({
                    fieldId: 'customform',
                    value: lookup[projId],
                    ignoreFieldChange: true,
                    fireSlavingSync: true
                });
            }
        }
    }

    return {
        fieldChanged: fieldChanged,
        pageInit: pageInit
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. Am I right in saying that this will only work in edit mode? Is there any way to get it to work when viewing the project in view mode?

Comment: I should also mention that when in edit mode, the custom form selection does change correctly, however the actual form itself does not change. It seems as though normally you would have to click the selection rather than just change the value of the field in order for it to actually execute the change. Can this be fixed by adding in a page reload after change?

Comment: @jtux you are correct, this will only function in edit mode. I also believe that it will only work as a client script and not on a before load user event script.